# How do i trim in javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how do i trim using this

```
 $('#type_of_station').text()
```

the result is

```
>>> $('#type_of_station').text()
"pizza delivery system "
```

As you can see there is a space after the last word

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery:
`str = jQuery.trim(str);`

JavaScript:
`str =  str.replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");`

Comment: What's wrong with it? `var str = "   foo   "; str = jQuery.trim(str); alert('"' + str + '"');` (shows "foo")

Comment: The ECMAScript 5 standard outlines a [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) function native to the `String` object. Currently, I believe, it's only available in JS >= 1.8.1 (meaning FireFox 3.5+). Hopefully others will follow suit eventually and `.trim()` will work on all modern browsers natively.

Comment: @clarkf - Safari and Chrome have it as well. According to this page it's coming in IE9: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974378(VS.85).aspx Nice thing is that jQuery's `$.trim()` [defaults to the native implementation](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L630) when it's available.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [JQuery.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) function.